# AltBeacon library - how to use in remote service

Tags: android

I am trying to use the AltBeacon library with the ranging feature in a remote service. However, I could not manage to get the beacon detection running successfully by now. When declaring the same service as local service everything works fine.

When the service runs in its own process the function startRangingBeaconsInRegion() seems to throw the following exception:

```
09-17 17:09:14.643  10709-10729/com.my.project E/Parcel﹕ Class not found when unmarshalling: org.altbeacon.beacon.service.StartRMData
    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.altbeacon.beacon.service.StartRMData
            at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
            at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:309)
            at android.os.Parcel.readParcelableCreator(Parcel.java:2281)
            at android.os.Parcel.readParcelable(Parcel.java:2245)
            at android.os.Message.readFromParcel(Message.java:571)
            at android.os.Message.access$000(Message.java:32)
            at android.os.Message$1.createFromParcel(Message.java:527)
            at android.os.Message$1.createFromParcel(Message.java:524)
            at android.os.IMessenger$Stub.onTransact(IMessenger.java:51)
            at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:446)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.altbeacon.beacon.service.StartRMData
            at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
            at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
            at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
            at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
            at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:309)
            at android.os.Parcel.readParcelableCreator(Parcel.java:2281)
            at android.os.Parcel.readParcelable(Parcel.java:2245)
            at android.os.Message.readFromParcel(Message.java:571)
            at android.os.Message.access$000(Message.java:32)
            at android.os.Message$1.createFromParcel(Message.java:527)
            at android.os.Message$1.createFromParcel(Message.java:524)
            at android.os.IMessenger$Stub.onTransact(IMessenger.java:51)
            at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:446)
     Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack available
09-17 17:09:14.643  10709-10729/com.my.project W/Binder﹕ Caught a RuntimeException from the binder stub implementation.
    android.os.BadParcelableException: ClassNotFoundException when unmarshalling: org.altbeacon.beacon.service.StartRMData
            at android.os.Parcel.readParcelableCreator(Parcel.java:2295)
            at android.os.Parcel.readParcelable(Parcel.java:2245)
            at android.os.Message.readFromParcel(Message.java:571)
            at android.os.Message.access$000(Message.java:32)
            at android.os.Message$1.createFromParcel(Message.java:527)
            at android.os.Message$1.createFromParcel(Message.java:524)
            at android.os.IMessenger$Stub.onTransact(IMessenger.java:51)
            at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:446)
```

Is there any solution for this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Android Beacon Library is not designed to be run in its own process, so what you describe is not possible.  You can see a more detailed discussion of why this is true in this issue discussion here:  https://github.com/AltBeacon/android-beacon-library/issues/291

Answer (score 1):

This is an old discussion, but as I found it now, I will post my solution. If you always want your Beacon Service to run in its own process, and therefore you need the altBeacon service to run in same process, it is very doable. Just have your service create the `BeaconManager` and add the following to your Manifest:

```
<!-- This is our own BeaconService. We run it in own process, as we don't want it affecting UI, and better crash control.
   This also solves the ACRA issue. -->
<service android:name=".BeaconControllerService"
         android:process=":my.BeaconControllerService"
         android:exported="false"
         android:enabled="true">

</service>

<!-- Override beacon library. Set it to our process -->

<receiver android:name="org.altbeacon.beacon.startup.StartupBroadcastReceiver"
          android:process=":my.BeaconControllerService"
          tools:replace="process" />
<service
    android:name="org.altbeacon.beacon.service.BeaconService"
    android:process=":my.BeaconControllerService"
    tools:replace="process" />
<service
    android:name="org.altbeacon.beacon.BeaconIntentProcessor"
    android:process=":my.BeaconControllerService"
    tools:replace="process" />
```

So far it is working for me. This should also solves the ACRA issue. Just remember, as its running in own process, if you want to bind from your application to your Service, you will have to use the `Message` class or an AIDL binder. See Android docs for info. Also, the `BeaconManager` has to be in your Service class, not your application.

Comment: Could you please add the BeaconControllerService class? I can't get it to compile for some reason.

Comment: not working for me :/ Can't get the detection running. There is no error or exception though